# How to change the container name in Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I deployed docker-compose.yml through Docker Swarm.

The container-name in docker-compose.yml was ignored.

I have to use the designated container name, but "docker container name" cannot be used.

Is there any way?

**Actually, I needed this task to map the container ip to /etc/hosts.**

**docker-compose's links, depends-on is doesn't work.**

**I solved this problem with the "docker inspect" command. and volume mount between docker inspect's result and container's /etc/hosts.**

Comment: for /etc/hosts mapping... -> 

docker ps -q | xargs -n 1 docker inspect --format '{{ .Name }} {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}} {{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' | sed 's#^/##'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected behavior.

As per Official Docker Doc

```
Note when using docker stack deploy

The [container_name][1] option is ignored when [deploying a stack in swarm mode][1]
```

**Note:** Checkout Other [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46485195/3098330)

Comment: Yeah... Thx for your answer. I took a detour to solve this problem. The detour method was written in edited question.